# How to fix org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "group.id" which has no default value

Tags: hive, apache-kafka

I have a Kafka topic setup and am attempting to create an external table in Hive to query the Kafka stream.

However, when querying the external table I get the error message

```
Error: java.io.IOException: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "group.id" which has no default value. (state=,code=0)
```

Tried putting `group.id` in the `server.properties` when starting the Kafka server.

Tried putting `group.id` in external table properties.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE kafka_table2
  (`timestamp` timestamp , `page` string,  `newPage` boolean,
  added int, deleted bigint, delta double)
  STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.kafka.KafkaStorageHandler'
  TBLPROPERTIES
  ("kafka.topic" = "connect-test", "kafka.bootstrap.servers"="mykafka:9092","kafka.group.id"="1")


INFO  : Completed compiling command(queryId=hive_20190426082255_729f8adb-bb23-4317-8f3f-2f9049b62bd7); Time taken: 0.6 seconds
INFO  : Executing command(queryId=hive_20190426082255_729f8adb-bb23-4317-8f3f-2f9049b62bd7): select * from kafka_table2
INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=hive_20190426082255_729f8adb-bb23-4317-8f3f-2f9049b62bd7); Time taken: 0.018 seconds
INFO  : OK
Error: java.io.IOException: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "group.id" which has no default value. (state=,code=0)
```

Comment: group.id is a consumer property, so it has to be set on the consumer side...

Comment: thanks for the response, this is the kafka-hive intregration, so there is no consumer configured.

Comment: Yes there is... Hive is reading a Kafka topic into a table, therefore it's opening a Consumer instance internally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put "kafka.**consumer**.group.id"="1" and not "kafka.group.id"="1" in TBLPROPERTIES.

See: https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/integrating-hive/content/hive_set_consumer_producer.html